# Display rounded product custom price with thousands separator using WooCommerce get_price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

With woocommerce I am trying to get a custom rounded product price with thousands separator and currency:

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    echo '$' . round((preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $product->get_price()) *1.04)); 
    // echo " - ";
    // echo number_format($product->get_price(), 0, '', '.') *1.04;
    ?>
```

The commented php code is the code that I have used before and it didn't round the value...

**Edit** *(Important)*:
This custom product price is the default price multiplied by 4% (x 1.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WC_Product` `get_price()` method **output a float number** and doesn't need `preg_replace()`…

The dedicated Woocommerce `wc_price()` formatting function, will add the necessary currency symbol and all needed separators **as they are set in Woocommerce general settings**…

So the final working code is:

```
<?php echo wc_price( round($product->get_price() * 1.04) ); ?>
```

Tested and works. It should solve everything.